# How to set a route before a component is created in unit test

Tags: angular6

I have a component which when created extracts a parameter from `url` and launches a query.

```
ngOnInit() {
   ....
 this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("my-id");
    console.log("will query db for question with id " + this.id);
    this.myService.getId(this.id)
  }
```

I want to unit-test the component but I can't figure out how to set the `url` before `TestBed` creates this component.

The url should be of format

```
{
    path:'id-details;my-id=:id',//  for eg id-details;my-id=1 
    component:MyComponent
  },
```

I thought I could set the route in `beforeEach` but that isn't working

```
beforeEach((done) => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    let router = TestBed.get(Router);
    let location = TestBed.get(Location);
    router.navigateByUrl("/id-details;my-id=1");
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
```

In above spec, the component gets created but I don't get id. I tried extracting params  in the followinng two ways but I always get `null`

```
 this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("my-id"); //get null
```

and

```
 this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id-details"); //get null
```

I also see the following error in the console

```
context.js:1972 Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'question-details;question-id=1' ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'question-details;question-id=1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 spyOn(component.route.snapshot.paramMap,"get").and.returnValue("some_id")
```

Or:

```
let fake_value = "value";
spyOn(component.route.snapshot.paramMap,"get").and.callFake(()=>{
    return fake_value;
});

fake_value = "another";
component.someMethod();
expect(...).toBe("another");

fake_value = "then_";
component.someMethod();
expect(...).toBe("then_");
```